# SSIS Column mapping problem in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a package to load multiple CSV files using for each loop container, the package runs with no error but there's a mismatch in columns data in the OLE DB destination, the mapping looks good in both source and destination but I'm not sure why this is happening, any ideas?

This is how the source CSV file where the exact row with the problem starts looks like:

[image]

This where the mismatch starts in the SQL Server:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the data in csv may have a column delimiter/row delimiter issue that shifts columns. What is is your column delimiter? As you have identified the file and row causing issue it will be easy to find the actual reason.

Open the file in notepad++ and check of all characters (View -> Show symbol -> All characters)